# Is there a way to change blob path in a blob binding for azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am using an azure function that is gonna save multiple xml files with different names to the same blob container. I want to use data from other binding for format the name.

Blob binding:

```
[Blob("outbound/", FileAccess.Write, Connection = 
Settings.InbundBlobConnectionString)] Stream outboundBlob
```

Is there a way I can manipulate the blob path using code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use [imperative binding pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime). In function method signature, add `Binder binder`, remove Blob input binding and try code below.

```
        string myBlobName = "valueGotFromOtherBinding";
        var attributes = new Attribute[]
        {
            new BlobAttribute($"outbound/{myBlobName}", FileAccess.Write),
            new StorageAccountAttribute(Settings.InbundBlobConnectionString)
        };
        using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(attributes))
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync("Conetent");
        }
```

Comment: It seems that i can only upload with Http and time trigger functions using this method. When i try using Cosmos trigger nothing happens have you experienced these problems?

Comment: @BjørnMarcusMotzfeldtAuberg Haven't met this before, the binder should work despite what trigger we use in the function.  Do you mind sharing your code that doesn't work? Better put a new post as it seems a problem different from this one.

Answer (score 1):

In the case when the blobName value is in the Trigger binding JSON payload (for instance in the message/request body), you can use a POCO object, see the following:

```
[QueueTrigger("myQueueName", Connection = "mySTORAGE")] POCO item,
[Blob("outbound/{blobName}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = Settings.InbundBlobConnectionString)] Stream outboundBlob

   …

public class POCO
{
  // ...
  public string blobName { get; set;}
}
```

Here's the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---json-payloads).

Comment: Nice solution! Add the link and JSON format requirement.